# "Flutter run" giving error in Mac OS once I change in pubpec.yaml file

Tags: flutter

Please check below error, I am getting below error once I did some changes in "pubspec.yaml" file.
When I initial setup the project It works, as I did some changes then I am getting below error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart
  side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
  sudo gem install cocoapods



Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            2.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/neeteshkeshari/Projects/development/song_app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file
    'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Looking forward for kind response.

Comment: did you run   sudo gem install cocoapods command in terminal ?

Comment: Can you try again after installing Cocoapods as the error telling you to so? Also explain what you've changed in pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the changes made to the pubspec file, you can do this by following either of the 3 options:

> Install it
>
> From the terminal: Run `flutter pub get`.

OR From Android Studio

> Click Packages get in the action ribbon at the top of
>   pubspec.yaml.

OR From VS Code:

> Click Get Packages located in right side
>   of the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.

Then run the following in the terminal:
`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

terminal:

> flutter pub get

or if you are using VSCode with the Flutter extension, you can simply do:

> CMD + S on your pubspec.yaml file (saving the file automatically calls flutter pub get)

if the error persists, you can try

> flutter clean

and then try "flutter pub get" again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for sharing your views.

Above issue has been fixed by below steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Run Below commands

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
pod setup
```

[CocoaPods will be available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2uGL.png)

3. Quit VC editor and reopen.
4. do flutter run

Above steps worked for me.

Thanks.